Phantom `play_pause` keypress events
I have been experiencing these phantom keystrokes where any app related to media (vlc, music, youtube) constantly plays and pauses or even re-opens after closed. only the foreground app is affected.

Ex.1 Open a video in vlc -> close the video -> video opens by itself and start playing
Ex.2 Restart mac -> music app opens by itself (not in startup itens) and start to constantly play and pause music.

At first i tough it was a problem related to Karabiner as it directly monitors and modifies these inputs from my keyboard but with it fully closed even checking on activity monitor for sub processes everything was closed and the problem could still be replicated. Same i could say from "winery" which was the last app i installed before experiencing this problem.
It is not a hardware problem as i would need to press both fn+f8 for play_pause to be triggered by my keyboard, and the problem is not reproduced in safe mode

After restarting in safe mode i could not reproduce the problem.
I cleared cache and log files and the problem still occurred
Even with no startup itens, the problem occurs, i restarted vlc and the problem still occurs.

Anyone knows how i can pinpoint the app activating these events? or what could cause it?
Info:
- software version: 14.4.1 (23E224)
- Model: MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2021
- Chip: Apple M1 Pro

